# How to open the mysql container docker in the mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a mysql container like this :
[image]

I want to open the mysql using mysql workbench, does anyone know how ??

I am still confused how to fill this data ..
[image]

I hope there is a solution to my problem

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**
You have to publish MySQL's port `3306` to the "outside" using the `-p` switch.

---

Container ports are not accessible by default to the "outside" and are only open to other containers in the same network (or the same docker-compose file.)

Run your MySQL image with `-p 15000:3306` (map local port 15000 to container's port 3306) then connect in the Workbench to `localhost` at port `15000`. You can choose any port you want, it can be 3306 too: `-p 3306:3306`.

Example `docker run` command:

```
docker run -it --rm -v mysql:/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3306 mysql
```

In case of `docker-compose`:

```
services:
  # …
  mysql:
    # …
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```